# Are these finite semirings known?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algorithms, semirings

I am trying to prove the properties below, and by doing this, I hope to find a way to speed up the computation of the below defined addition and multiplication. I am also interested if these finite semirings are known (If the algebraic structure can be proven to be a semiring).

Context:
I am interpreting the factorization trees, such as $T_{19}$ shown here, which knows the factorization of every number $1 \le m \le 19$, as decision trees for numbers which might be larger then $19$. For this interpretation I take every node of the tree as asking recursively the number $N$ a question concerning its smallest prime divisor.

[image: factorization_tree_for_n=_19]

Each number $N$ then is classified / projected on one of the numbers $1,\cdots,19$, which I denote as $\pi_n(N)$.

Idea: First we define $\pi_n(N):= \max_{ x \le N, x \in D(N) \cap [n]} x $, where $D(N)$ denotes the set of divisors of $N$ which are sorted with the lexicographic prime factorization ordering, which
is denoted as $\le$ and the $\max$ is being taken with respect to this ordering and $[n]:=\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$.

Here are some values calculated for $\pi_n(N)$:

[image: table_for_pi_n(N)]

Properties of $\pi_n(N)$:

- $\forall m \leq n \in \mathbb{N}: \pi_n(m) = m$
- $\forall N \in \mathbb{N}: 1 \leq \pi_n(N) \leq n$
- $\forall N \in \mathbb{N}: \pi_n(N) \, | \, N$
- $\forall N \in \mathbb{N}: \pi_n(\pi_n(N)) = \pi_n(N)$
- (?) $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{N}: \pi_n(a \cdot b) \le \pi_n(a) \cdot \pi_n(b)$

We define the "successor" function on $[n]:=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$:

$$
\psi: [n] \rightarrow [n]
$$

$$
m \mapsto \pi_n(m+1)
$$

We define addition on $[n]$ as $\oplus$:

$$
\oplus: [n] \times [n] \rightarrow [n]
$$

$$(a , b) \mapsto \psi^{(b)}(a) = \psi(\psi(...(\psi(a))...))$$

where the successor function $\psi$ is iterated $b$ times.

We define the multiplication on $[n]$ as $\otimes$:

$$\otimes: [n] \times [n] \rightarrow [n]$$

$$
(a , b) \mapsto a \oplus a \oplus \ldots \oplus a
$$

where the addition will be iterated $b$ times.

**Conjectured properties of the operations**

- $([n], \oplus,\otimes)$ is an abelian semiring (without neccessarily having a $0$ and a $1$).

**Idea for notation**

Idea for notation: $a \equiv b \operatorname{proj}(n)$ if and only if $\pi_n(a) = \pi_n(b)$.

Therefore,

- $a \operatorname{proj}(n) := \pi_n(a)$
- $a + b \operatorname{proj}(n) := \pi_n(a) \oplus \pi_n(b)$
- $a \cdot b \operatorname{proj}(n) := \pi_n(a) \otimes \pi_n(b)$ (Definition consisent on equivalence classes?)

**Conjectured properties (semiring definition)**

- $a + b \operatorname{proj}(n) \equiv b + a \operatorname{proj}(n)$
- $a \cdot b \operatorname{proj} \equiv b \cdot a \operatorname{proj}(n)$
- $a \cdot (b + c) \operatorname{proj}(n) \equiv a \cdot b + a \cdot c \operatorname{proj}(n)$
- $a + (b+c) \operatorname{proj}(n) \equiv (a+b) + c \operatorname{proj}(n)$
- $a \cdot (b \cdot c) \operatorname{proj}(n) \equiv (a \cdot b) \cdot c \operatorname{proj}(n)$

We get:

$$
a = b \iff \forall n \in \mathbb{N}: a \operatorname{proj}(n) \equiv b \operatorname{proj}(n)
$$

If, $a = b \implies \forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \pi_n(a) = \pi_n(b)$, thus $a \equiv b \operatorname{proj}(n)$.
On the other hand, if we let $n = \max(a,b)$, then $1 \leq a, b \leq n \implies a = \pi_n(a) = \pi_n(b) = b$.

**Examples of addition and multiplication tables**
$\oplus$ for $n=1$
$$ \left(\begin{array}{r}1\end{array}\right) $$

$\otimes$ for $n=1$
$$ \left(\begin{array}{r}1\end{array}\right) $$

$\oplus$ for $n=2$
$$ \left(\begin{array}{rr}2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{array}\right) $$

$\otimes$ for $n=2$
$$ \left(\begin{array}{rr}1 & 2 \\ 2 & 2 \end{array}\right) $$

$\oplus$ for $n=3$
$$ \left(\begin{array}{rrr}2 & 3 & 2 \\ 3 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 3 & 2\end{array}\right) $$

$\otimes$ for $n=3$
$$ \left(\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
2 & 2 & 2 \\ 
3 & 2 & 3\end{array}\right) $$

$\oplus$ for $n=4$
$$ \left(\begin{array}{rrrr}2 & 3 & 4 & 1 \\ 3 & 4 & 1 & 2 \\ 4 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\end{array}\right) $$

$\otimes$ for $n=4$
$$ \left(\begin{array}{rrrr}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 2 & 4 & 2 & 4 \\ 3 & 2 & 1 & 4 \\ 4 & 4 & 4 & 4\end{array}\right) $$

$\oplus$ for $n=5$
$$ \left(\begin{array}{rrrrr}
2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 2 \\
3 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
5 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 2
\end{array}\right) $$

$\otimes$ for $n=5$
$$ \left(\begin{array}{rrrrr}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
2 & 4 & 2 & 4 & 2 \\
3 & 2 & 5 & 4 & 3 \\
4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 \\
5 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5
\end{array}\right) $$

**Visualization of addition and multiplication tables for** $n=100$

[image: addition_table_for_n=100]

[image: multiplication_table_for_n=100]

**Successor Graphs**
Let $G_n = ([n],E_n)$ be the directed graph defined on the vertices $[n]$ and between the vertices $a,b$ is an edge $a \rightarrow b \iff b = \pi_n(a+1)$.

Some graphs are shown in the following two tables.
[image: table_with_successor_graph_for_n=3,4,5,6]

[image: table_with_successor_graph_for_n=7,8,9,10]

We can see from this graphs a certain modularity and make the conjecture, that we have:

\begin{equation}
    a \oplus b = 
    \begin{cases} 
      a+b & \text{if } a+b \le n, \\
      (a+b-\pi_n(n+1)) (\mod n-\pi_n(n+1)+1) + \pi_n(n+1), \text{ otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    a \otimes b = 
    \begin{cases} 
      a \cdot b & \text{if } a \cdot b \le n, \\
      (a \cdot b-\pi_n(n+1)) (\mod n-\pi_n(n+1)+1) + \pi_n(n+1), \text{ otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

These two equations could be used to speed up the computation of $\oplus, \otimes$ and would prove that the structure above is an abelian semiring.

**Question: Can these two equation above about $\oplus,\otimes$ be proven?**

Comment: I do not understand the downvote. :-(

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but the downvote might have to do with the fact that you included so many screens of data, which makes it very hard to figure out what's important and what's not.

Comment: @JoeSilverman: I thought that more examples are better. I will change that. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I think you might have either a typo or thinko — above the tree you mention querying a number about its smallest prime divisor, but the way you recurse suggests that the key quantity is actually the number's _largest_ prime divisor. You do eventually get to the smallest at the top level by stripping away all the larger ones, but every arrow from one level to the next is actually a multiplication by that largest prime divisor.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thank you for your comment. I will answer your question tomorrow.

Comment: I did not downvote, but a few more notes on why you might have gotten downvoted, things that suggest this question is not research-level: (1) your definition of $\pi_n(N)$ has the condition $x\in D(n)\cap[n]$, but trivially $D(n)\subset [n]$, so the intersection isn't needed. (2) Of the conjectured properties of $\pi$ that you mention, the second one is trivial and the first and third are almost trivially false: $\pi_8(7)=4$ and $\pi_5(8)=5$. Perhaps you mean $\pi_n(N)\mid n$? But this is also trivial, since the domain over which the max is taken is just the divisors of $n$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Thanks for the pointer with $D(n)$. It should have been $D(N)$ and yes, the way $\pi_n(N)$ is defined make the properties you mention trivial, which I have also changed. It does not make the quesiton less research-level, because it still is the question about the semirings if it is new or not.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: To come back to your question about the tree: First the tree is $T_n$ constructed. Then the numbers $N$ which might be bigger thant $n$ are classified based on their smallest prime divisiors recursively on the nodes of the tree. You are right, I have not given the precise definition and it should be proven that those definitions of $\pi_n(N)$ are indeed equivalent.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: I have updated the question with a table for $\pi_n(N)$ as example.

Comment: @JoeSilverman: I have updated the question with the hope that it now becomes more clear. If there is still anything unclear, please do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: @JoeSilverman: I hope that the question is now more focused and clear.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Is there anything else which I can improve with the question?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe this addition is commutative or associative?

Comment: @CommandMaster: Yes, the '$mod$-equations' would prove this, and also I have done some experiments on the computer for small values of $n$.

Comment: related: http://www.orges-leka.de/a_class_of_number_theoretic_finite_semirings.pdf